# JQuery $(".some-element-id").length returns 0 after I create them using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

So I have a focusout event bound to an input field which creates a div element using JQuery with a class name. Before this div is created and added after the input field I am checking if there are any such elements present and if so removing them. This is my code:

```
$("#client-first-name").focusout(function() {


        var test = $(".field-validation-message").length;
        //remove all previous error divs
        if($(".field-validation-message").length) {
            $(".field-validation-message").remove();
        }


        if(checkName("client-first-name") != "") {
            $("#client-first-name").after($('<div />', {
                class: '.field-validation-message',
            }).html('test'));
        }
    });
```

The function checkName just checks if there are any errors in the input field. The test variable is always 0 (checked using DevTools).

Any Ideas?

Comment: You should use `.size()` instead of `length`

Comment: so the problem that test variable  is 0?

Comment: Provide your HTML for more detail.

Comment: .size() did not work. test variable is always 0 yes (checking using DevTools on chrome. as for after I believe it is because the new div appears after the #client-first-name input tag

Comment: Because you have an extra dot in class declaration. You have `class: '.field-validation-message',` but it should be `class: 'field-validation-message',`

Comment: Ahhh so the 'class' property already adds a dot. Thanks, works perfectly now!

Comment: No it isnt adding a dot to classname. The dot is a class selector just like e.g ,# is for ID

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is the class you are adding to the new div should not be prepended with a `.`.

```js
$("#client-first-name").focusout(function() {


  var test = $(".field-validation-message").length;
  console.log(test);
  //remove all previous error divs
  if ($(".field-validation-message").length) {
    $(".field-validation-message").remove();
  }


  if (checkName("client-first-name") != "") {
    $("#client-first-name").after($('<div />', {
      class: 'field-validation-message',  //here was the problem!!
    }).html('test'));
  }
});

function checkName(selector) {
  return "no way";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='client-first-name'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove `$(".field-validation-message")` each time you blur out?

```
$("#client-first-name").focusout(function() {
        $(".field-validation-message").remove();

        if(checkName("client-first-name") != "") {
            // Or here if you only want to remove when appending 
            // $(".field-validation-message").remove();

            $("#client-first-name").after($('<div />', {
                class: '.field-validation-message',
            }).html('test'));
        }
});
```